# RMagick: How to check if all pixels in a particular area of the image are transparent?

Tags: ruby, png, imagemagick, rmagick

I would like to create a code from a given image. For example, this image:

[image]

should get the code `111-111-010`.

(Suppose it's a `png` image and all pixels except the banana itself are transparent.)

If all pixels in a particular square are transparent, the value of this square is `0`, otherwise it's `1`.

So, given an image, I would like to divide it to squares of a given size (e.g. the banana image is `300x300` pixels, and the squares are `100x100`), and then to create a code (string) which is built like described above.

The easiest way would probably be by using `each_pixel` and just check manually if all pixels in a square are transparent. Is there a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take your existing image and shrink it to that 3x3 size:

```
play = image.resize(3, 3, CubicFilter, 0.5)
```

Then you can create the code by checking each remaining pixel using:

```
code = ""
(0..2).each do |ix|
  (0..2).each do |iy|
    code += play.pixel_color(ix,iy).opacity == 65535 ? "0" : "1"
    code += iy == 2 ? "-" : "" unless ix == 2 && iy == 2
  end
end
```

I compare opacity to `65535` because when I inspected a pixel I knew was transparent this is what returned:

```
=> red=65535, green=65535, blue=65535, opacity=65535
```

Comment: This code produces `011-111-111`. It looks like it missed the other transparent point.